# What is the "lighting-color" CSS style?

Tags: css

So I was messing around in Firefox's inspector tool and began to add a line-height style when I noticed something new: there appears a `lighting-color` style, which naturally makes me ask

## What?!

What is this "lighting" style? I can't seem to find anything except `-color` associated with it, and after searching around the net I'm still scratching my head. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The property that you originally reference is lighting-color, not lightning-color. According to Mozilla:

The lighting-color attribute defines the color of the light source for filter primitives elements  and `<fespecularlighting>`.

So, it seems to be dealing with 3D lighting.

Comment: Seems I either need sleep or new glasses, likely both. Much better search results for 'lighting' instead of 'lightning'. Was kinda hoping this was much cooler :)